# Providing automated login credentials in Pre-launch test of Google play console [Ionic]

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I recently uploaded my first ionic app on google play. I started exploring the google play console and came across the Pre-launch tests.

We need to provide android resource name for the text-field for login, password and button for Sign-In button to make it work.

Any idea on how I could get this android resource names, or attach them to my elements.
Or a way to get the resource name out of a built apk. I am not much familiar with the tools available for android development.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not works with Ionic.

Note: Credentials can only be automatically inserted into Android apps that use standard Android widgets. Credentials can't be used in apps that use OpenGL to render custom controls or apps that use a WebView for a web-based authentication flow.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7002270?hl=en#signin

Comment: so what did you do about it? did your app get accepted? and how do you provide the credentials?

Comment: Yes, my app has been accepted without tests. I don't provide any credentials.

Comment: You can provide different credentials in a different menu that will be used for Review (at least the first review seems to be done by a real person). The pre-launch report is more like a service for the devs that gives valuable insights into app performance and usability for free - which is why I would really like to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Todo this you need access to the xml layout file for the apps login page.

This will be located in: `project -> app -> src -> main -> res -> layout`

Within that file you can get the following information needed.

**Username resource name:** Name of your username (email) [EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText) resource, skipping the `R.id` part, so for `R.id.edit_text_email` input `edit_text_email`

**Password resource name:** Same as above, but for password. Again, skip the `R.id`, e.g. `edit_text_password`

**Sign-in button resource name:** Same as above, but for the login [Button](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button). Again, skip the `R.id`, e.g. `btn_login`

**Username:** username or email you'd use for testing, e.g. `test@mywebsite.com`

**Password:** password you'd use for testing, e.g. `testTEST123`

This information will have to be entered in the apps Pre-launch report settings: `Google Play Console -> All applications -> <app> -> Release management -> Pre-launch report -> Settings`

Addition to this, here are some helpful Google links:

- [Use pre-launch and crash reports to improve your app](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/pre-launch-crash-reports)
- [Use pre-launch reports to identify issues](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7002270?hl=en-GB)

Referenced from [Voy's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3508719/voy) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42468839/3625488).

Comment: You answer is correct for a native android app, not for an app written with ionic.

Comment: if you supply credentials, does the testing do things like click buttons that trigger api inserts and stuff on the connector back end? - our app even though in development is in testing with a testing group.  I wouldn't want their automation in testing to do things like do api calls the app does....