# How to add credentials to firebse testlab for custom signin in flutter android app

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, automated-tests, firebase-test-lab

I am pushing flutter(android) app to firebase testlab, for robo test.
App has login with OTP, as login process.
where should I add credentials like (name, email, mobile and OTP) in testlab for robo test.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38260874/how-to-provide-login-credentials-to-an-automated-android-test)
this fix is for native android project right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robo currently does not support Flutter apps.  It only supports native Android and iOS apps that use native widgets.  Please see the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/robo-ux-test#non-android_widgets) on that.  Feel free to [file a feature request with Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).